# stripe split showing incomplete status using node js

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I have project requirement in which I have to apply split payment. I have followed "Direct charges", "Destination charges" and "separate charges and transfers". While try to use all of these I am getting payment status as "incomplete". I have attached the image.

[image]

Currently I am using this approach:

```
 stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: 100 * 10, //500 
        currency: 'usd',
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        // transfer_group: 'ORDER10',
        transfer_data: {
          destination: "acct_1KUQmWR4rcIHCakb"
        }
      }).then((res_c) => console.log("=-=--==-=-res", res_c));
```

Reference link: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges

I am able to see the log but on the dashboard, the status shows incomplete (as shown in the image attachment)

Am I missing something? Please help me out!

Answer (score 1):

Creating a PaymentIntent does not automatically charge the customer, there are more steps to take.
Overall the next step is that you should send the `client_secret` to your `frontend` and have your customer complete the payment flow: use either `PaymentElement` or `CardElement` and pass the `client_secret` of your `PI` to it, once the customers submits his payment details you should call either [confirmPayment](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_payment) or [confirmCardPayment](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment) respectively.

You can read more about this [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/creating-a-payments-page?destination-or-direct=destination-charges).